# What happen if not use FILE in a recipe?

Tags: build, yocto, openembedded

In yocto recipe, we can use `FILE` to assign which file or directory will be existed (this is my understanding).

What would happen if don’t assign value to `FILE`?

Ex:

```
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/local/bin/foo.sh"

do_install_append () {
  install -m 755 -d ${D}/usr/local/bin
  install -m 555 ${S}/foo.sh ${D}/usr/local/bin/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILES_<packagename>` variables define what files will be included in the package (`${PN}` refers to the recipes main package). The variables have default values (see `meta/conf/bitbake.conf`). These default values can be changed by your recipe or a class it inherits. You can check the final values with `bitbake -e <recipe>|grep ^FILES_`.

If your recipe installs files that are not included in the final `FILES_*` values, bitbake will complain.